# Producing UNIX timestamp out of datetime passed in C

Tags: c, datetime, timestamp, redhat, time-t

I'm porting a C app from Solaris to RedHat, and this function does not work very well on RedHat (and I need your help determing why):

```
int toTimestamp (const char *InputDate, const char *DateFormat, time_t *lTimestamp){
    struct tm tm;

    if (NULL == strptime(InputDate, DateFormat, &tm)){
        return FALSE;
    }
    *lTimestamp = mktime(&tm);
    return TRUE;    
}
```

Basically, it produces UNIX timestamp out of datetime passed in as a string, with specified format.

```
char *effPaymentDate = NULL;
char *CohDueDate = NULL;
//...
effPaymentDate = PayRec->RecDate;//char RecDate[8+1];, value 20141005
CohDueDate = PayRec->DueDate;//char DueDate[8+1];, value 20140820

time_t currentDateUNIX;
time_t DueDateUNIX;
if (FALSE == toTimestamp(CohDueDate, "%Y%m%d", &DueDateUNIX) ||
     FALSE == toTimestamp(effPaymentDate, "%Y%m%d", &currentDateUNIX)) {
  return NULL;
}
//...
```

However, it does not seem to work correctly (works OK for effPaymentDate, gives wrong dates for CohDueDate - i.e. year 2543) - any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR:

You need to initialize `tm` before passing it to APIs:

```
memset(&tm, 0, sizeof tm);
```

Why ?

`strptime` might fail without you noticed it:

```
$ man strptime
```

> RETURN VALUE
>   The return value of the function is a pointer to  the  first  character
>   not processed in this function call.  In case the input string contains
>   more characters than required by the format  string  the  return  value
>   points  right  after  the  last  consumed input character.  In case the
>   whole input string is consumed the return value points to the null byte
>   at the end of the string.  If strptime() fails to match all of the for‐
>   mat string and therefore an error occurred the function returns NULL.
>
> NOTES
>
> In principle, this function does not initialize tm but stores only
>   the values specified.  This means that tm should be initialized
>   before the call.  Details differ a bit between different UNIX
>   systems.  The glibc implementation does not touch those fields which
>   are not explicitly specified, except that it recomputes the tm_wday
>   and tm_yday field if any of the year, month, or day elements changed.

So because `tm` is not set to 0, some fields may contain random values.

Moreover:

```
$ man mktime
```

> The  mktime()  function  modifies  the  fields  of the tm structure as
>   follows: tm_wday and
>   tm_yday are set to values determined from the contents of the other  fields;  if  structure
>   members are outside their valid interval, they will be normalized (so that, for example, 40
>   October is changed into 9 November); tm_isdst is set (regardless of its initial value) to a
>   positive value or to 0, respectively, to indicate whether DST is or is not in effect at the
>   specified time.  Calling mktime() also sets the external variable tzname  with  information
>   about the current timezone.

The random values are likely to be out of range, and `mktime` tries to normalize it.
It did a good job though, but the `year` betrayed it !

Comment: although the solution is absolutely correct,  you maybe could add that quotation from the man page (in "Notes") which probably explains OP's problem: "In principle, this function does not initialize tm but stores only the values specified.  This means that tm should be initialized before the call."

Comment: Recommend showing how to set `tm` to `0`.  As `struct tm` may have fields other than the usual 9, doing something like `memset(&tm, 0, sizeof tm)` or `struct tm tm = { 0}` is good.  Too many code samples I've seen where only 6 of the 9 (missing `tm_isdst`) are initialized which leads to UB.